# non empty ListView giving error of Invalid index 0, size is 0

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView fragment in which I have registered the ListView for a context menu:

```
CourseArrayAdapter adapter = new CourseArrayAdapter(getActivity(), register.getCourseListByGrade(grade));
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setLongClickable(true);
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

I am confident that my adapter contains a non-empty list because it the ListView is populated with my custom views.

Context menu related methods:

```
    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_course_context, menu);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
    menu.setHeaderTitle(((CourseArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(info.position).getCourseName());
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_remove:
            register.removeCourse(((CourseArrayAdapter) getListAdapter()).getItem(((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo()).position).getId());
            return true;
        case R.id.action_edit:
            register.editCourse(((CourseArrayAdapter) getListAdapter()).getItem(((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo()).position).getId());
            return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Calling `getListAdapter().getItem(info.position)` in `onCreatedContextMenu` works without error and shows the correct menu title. However upon clicking on option the following error is displayed:

`08-14 16:02:46.964    1923-1923/com.andhruv.schoolapp E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
            at com.andhruv.schoolapp.CourseListFragment.onContextItemSelected(CourseListFragment.java:62)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performContextItemSelected(Fragment.java:1912)`

CourseListFragment.java:62 is the line

```
register.editCourse(((CourseArrayAdapter) getListAdapter()).getItem(((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo()).position).getId());
```

CourseArrayAdapter:

```
class CourseArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Course> {
private Gpa gpaCalculator;

public CourseArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Course> values) {
    super(context, 0,values);
    gpaCalculator = new Gpa();
}

@Override
public  View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_course,parent,false);
    TextView textViewCourseName = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCourseName);
    TextView textViewGpa = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewGpa);
    TextView textViewGrade = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewGrade);
    TextView textViewType = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewType);
    TextView textViewCategory = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory);
    textViewCourseName.setText(getItem(position).getCourseName());
    textViewGpa.setText(String.valueOf(gpaCalculator.calcCourseVal(getItem(position).getLetterGrade(),getItem(position).getCourseLevel(),true)));
    textViewType.setText(String.valueOf(getItem(position).getCourseLevel()));
    textViewCategory.setText(String.valueOf(getItem(position).getCategory()).replace('_',' '));
    textViewGrade.setText(String.valueOf(getItem(position).getLetterGrade()));
    textViewCourseName.setTag(getItem(position).getId());
    return rowView;
}
```

}

Why does the call `((CourseArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(info.position)` work in onCreateContextMenu but not in onContextItemSelected?

Comment: Show code of CourseArrayAdapter. You probably did not add code to getItem() or getCount() correctly.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid okay i updated it

Comment: facing exactly same issue. have you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're not modifying the adapter correctly in code of:

```
register.removeCourse(((CourseArrayAdapter) getListAdapter()).getItem(((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo()).position).getId());
```

OR

```
register.editCourse(...
```

It is hard for me to suggest a complete code fix for this since your code does not fit into my coding style and of course I don't know your code well. However I am providing sample code to remove items from the adapter. Basically if you want to add, remove, or edit data from your collection of `List<Course>`, you need to notify the adapter.
Sample code:

```
adapter = getListAdapter();

adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I hope that's clear enough for you to get a good start.